# HTTP client-server, I don't think i'm closing my client side connections with BasicResponseHandler()

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I have a server implemented using Apache HTTPCore which can accept posts from an httpclient implementation. I have enough of it working so that I can send to the server, processes the post contents, and get the response back on the client. Everything seems to work, however I am noticing that the server keeps the connection alive until it times out, even though the client connection has completed successfully. I'm assuming that I need to close the connection on the client side after receiving the response, however I believe I am already doing that as I am using `BasicResponseHandler()`, which returns a `String`, so I can't figure out what if anything I need to actually close.

Any thoughts on this? I was going to try using a different response handler that returns an `InputStream`, and see if closing that works, but I assumed that `BasicResponseHandler`was doing that behind the scenes already as it returns a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server hasn't read an EOS, the client hasn't closed the connection. Having a read timeout on the connection to the client is the correct strategy.